# How to join tables in r2dbc?

Tags: project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

In java reactor, r2dbc. I have two tables A, B. I also have repositories for them defined.
How can i get data made up of A join B?

I only come up with the following approach:
call databaseClient.select from A and consequently in a loop call select from B.

But i want more efficient and reactive way. How to do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Using SQL.

Spring Data's `DatabaseClient` is an improved and reactive variant for R2DBC of what `JdbcTemplate` is for JDBC. It encapsulates various execution modes, resource management, and exception translation. Its fluent API select/insert/update/delete methods are suitable for simple and flat queries. Everything that goes beyond the provided API is subject to SQL usage.

That being said, the method you're looking for is `DatabaseClient.execute(…)`:

```
DatabaseClient client = …;
client.execute("SELECT person.age, address.street FROM person INNER JOIN address ON person.address = address.id");
```

The exact same goes for repository `@Query` methods.

Calling the database during result processing is a good way to lock up the entire result processing as results are fetched stream-wise. Issuing a query while not all results are fetched yet can exhaust the prefetch buffer of 128 or 256 items and cause your result stream to stuck. Additionally, you're creating an N+1 problem.

Comment: problem with your approach lies in impossibility of mapping result  on an entity. So, lets take your example of person and address query, i have no idea how to map the result of select on arbitrary entity PersonalInfo(except of map())

Comment: Spring Data R2DBC is not an object-relational mapper in the first place. You can map single rows to single objects. You can use convention-based mapping for all results via `execute(…).as(PersonalInfo.class).fetch().all()`.

Comment: this `execute(…).as(PersonalInfo.class)` is still valid? I could not find

Comment: @RamPrakash take a read at this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/#upgrading.1.1-1.2. Basically the `execute` method has been replaced by `sql` method

Comment: @mp911de Could you please have a look at my question on r2dbc here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76755286/2886891 ? Thanks a lot.